# Count the total number of words in a .pdf document using Python

Tags: python

I don't seem to be able to count the total number of words in a .pdf file. I assume one of the easiest ways is to count the number of spaces. I've tried the two following approaches:

1). Open the file and count the number of spaces in each page:

```
import PyPDF2

filename = 'Text.pdf'

pdf_file = open(filename, 'r')

read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()

pattern = ' '
total_number_of_spaces = 0

for page in range(number_of_pages):
    read_page = read_pdf.getPage(page)
    page_content = read_page.extractText()
    counted_spaces_per_page = page_content.count(pattern)
    total_number_of_spaces += counted_spaces_per_page

print(total_number_of_spaces)
```

The problem here is that the text that I see in Python has additional spaces, as in "A 1 B 2" instead of "A1B2", "n umerous" instead of "numerous" or "[ 1 ]" instead of "[1]".

2). Save the data in an intermediate file and read this file as a second step.

```
import re
import PyPDF2

filename = 'Text.pdf'

pdf_file = open(filename, 'r')

read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()

new_filename = 'new_file.csv'

pattern = r'\s+'
repl = r' '

saved = []

for page in range(number_of_pages):
    read_page = read_pdf.getPage(page)
    page_content = read_page.extractText()
    to_be_saved = re.sub(pattern, repl, page_content)
    saved.append(to_be_saved)

new_file = open(new_filename, 'w')

for element in saved:
    new_file.write(str(element))

new_file.close()

with open(new_filename, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines)
    all_spaces = re.findall(repl, str(lines))
    print(len(all_spaces))
```

But of course, the abovementioned problem persists.

Probably the correct question to ask would be "How do I get rid of extra space constants in a .pdf document opened in Python?" but I guess someone may know a different method of counting words in a .pdf document using Python (unrelated to the number of spaces)?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? i.e.:

```
import textract, re
text = textract.process("sample.pdf") # http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
words = re.findall(r"[^\W_]+", text, re.MULTILINE) # regex demo and explanation - https://regex101.com/r/U7WMSA/1
print(len(words))
print(words)
# 177
# ['A', 'Simple', 'PDF', 'File', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'small', 'demonstration', 'pdf', 'file', 'just', 'for', 'use', 'in', 'the', 'Virtual', 'Mechanics', 'tutorials', 'More', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'Boring', 'zzzzz', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'Even', 'more', 'Continued', 'on', 'page', '2', 'Simple', 'PDF', 'File', '2', 'continued', 'from', 'page', '1', 'Yet', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'Oh', 'how', 'boring', 'typing', 'this', 'stuff', 'But', 'not', 'as', 'boring', 'as', 'watching', 'paint', 'dry', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'And', 'more', 'text', 'Boring', 'More', 'a', 'little', 'more', 'text', 'The', 'end', 'and', 'just', 'as', 'well']
```

---

Sources:

1. [Python Word Count (Filter out Punctuation, Dictionary Manipulation,
   and Sorting Lists)](https://codeburst.io/python-basics-11-word-count-filter-out-punctuation-dictionary-manipulation-and-sorting-lists-3f6c55420855)
2. [How to Extract Words from PDFs with Python](https://medium.com/@rqaiserr/how-to-convert-pdfs-into-searchable-key-words-with-python-85aab86c544f)

Comment: No but I will if I manage to solve an error that comes up when installing the package

Comment: Sorry to hear that, my install went smooth on windows. It's most certainly related to unavailable dependencies for your system. You can still use your code to parse the `text`, but pass it to the `re.findall` on my answer instead, the results should be similar.

Comment: This works but not the way I was expecting. When I do this to improve my first code, I get a list of all words. It so happens that their total number is slightly above the "correct" number. The problem is combinations of letters and numbers within one word, such as "A1".

Comment: Try to improve the regex in a way that it matches only the words you want. You may also create a list of *forbidden* words  that will be  removed from the final result.

Comment: I'll give it a think. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i really apreciate that you add some of your sources!

Comment: i have a ""ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textract' '""

Comment: @Momo https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html